# django-channels webSocketBridge read data sent by consumers

Tags: django, django-channels

I am having a simple setup with testing channels 2.0.

I have a routed consumer with three methods:
**consumers.py**

```
from channels.generic.websocket import JsonWebsocketConsumer
from datetime import datetime

#  
class Feedback_001_Consumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self,text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        self.accept()
        self.send_json("Connection for Feedback 1 ready.")
    #
    def receive(self,text_data=None):
        #self.accept()
        self.send_json("{}".format(datetime.now()))
        print(datetime.now())
    #
    def disconnect(self,close_code):
        pass
```

and my js looks like this:

```
const webSocketBridge = new channels.WebSocketBridge();
#...
webSocketBridge.connect('my_route/etc...');
#...
console.log(webSocketBridge.send(''));
```

While the datetime is printing in the console, I cannot get the one sent by `self.send_json` in the `receive method` of the consumer. What would be the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consumer.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import JsonWebsocketConsumer
from datetime import datetime

class Feedback_001_Consumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def receive_json(self, content, **kwargs):
        if content['command'] == 'time':
            time = datetime.now()
            self.send_json({'time': time})
            print(time)

    def disconnect(self,close_code):
        pass
```

your.js

```
webSocketBridge.socket.onopen = function(){
    console.log('connected to server');
// do something else. eg
    webSocketBridge.send({'command': 'time'}) 
};

webSocketBridge.listen(function(message, stream){
    var data = message.time
    console.log(data)
});
```